# How to stop Node.js from printing data to console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have this Code in node

```
var io = require('socket.io'), connect = require('connect');

var pg = require('pg');

var connectionString = "Some connection string";  

var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000);
var chat_room = io.listen(app);
var DataArrayRows=[];

setInterval(function(){
       pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
        client.query('select * from jctsl_get_all_notifications_v1()', function(err, result) {
            DataArrayRows=result.rows;
            done();
        });
       });
},10000);

chat_room.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  chat_room.sockets.emit('entrance',{message:DataArrayRows}); 
  setInterval(function(){
      chat_room.sockets.emit('entrance',{message:DataArrayRows});   
  },10000);    
});
```

In the code, I've not written any `console.log()` statement but still on every request to database, the returned rows are displayed on the console window.

How can I stop node from doing that?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the log level lower

```
var chat_room = io.listen(app);

chat_room.set('log level', 0);
```

The log level defaults to 3
The amount of detail that the server should output to the logger.

0 - error
1 - warn
2 - info
3 - debug

Comment: Error: Object #<Object> has no method set

Comment: @writeToBhuwan - Oh, `io` isn't the socket, `chat_room` is, what a strange way to do it ?

Comment: Can you please see if the code is justified? I mean performance wise.. It is good?

Comment: That depends on what it does, there could be better ways to do certain things etc. but the posted code seems fine, there's nothing that stands out as inefficient or "wrong"!